# "You have been logged in with a temporary profile" - Windows 7 PC on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, user-profile, roaming-profile, profile

I know it is one of the most frequently asked question. But I've tried all the fixes which didn't help. We have Windows 2012 Server R2 as DC and a series of Windows 7 systems connected to it. Suddenly, we have been receiving the notification "You have been logged in with a temporary profile" whenever we login to our server for only some of the users. I've tried fixing both the systems and the domain. Nothing helped. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1):

We get this every so often and what I always do is go into the registry and rename the profile in the 'ProfileList'. I then rename the profile folder in c:\users. Let the user log back in and see if it creates a new profile. If that doesn't work, I replace the DefaultProfile folder on that system and that usually does it. Have you tried this yet? I believe the direct path to the profilelist in the registry is:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

Comment: Sorry pal! This doesn't help. I've tried it already